# Unity2D после смерти врага не появляются партиклы

Tags: c#, разработка-игр, unity3d

Сделал партикл при попадании по врагу, все отлично работает. Но есть одна проблема, когда умирает enemy то на его месте нету партиклов, я уже столько всего перепробовал, но ничего не выходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Enemy : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health;
    public float speed;

    public GameObject effect;

    private void Update() 
    {
        if (health <= 0)
        {
            // строчка ниже и создает партикл
            Instantiate(effect, transform.position, Quaternion.identity);
            Destroy(gameObject);
        }
        transform.Translate(Vector2.left * speed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    public void TakeDamage(int damage)
    {
        health -= damage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Во первых проверку на смерть делай не в `Update`, а при получении урона

Во вторых вместо `Instantiate` закешируй `ParticleSystem` и запускай его через `.Play()`.
Сделай одну систему частиц на сцене и в `Start()` ищи ее через `GameObject.Find().GetComponent<ParticleSystem>()` - по имени, или через `GameObject.FindWithTag().GetComponent<ParticleSystem>()` - по тегу

В третьих в инспекторе партикла поставь `Simulation Space` >> `World` и убери галочку с `Looping`

Вот мой пример:

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Drop : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ParticleSystem _particles = default;

    private void Awake()
    {
        _particles = GameObject.FindWithTag("DropParticles").GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
    }

    private void Return()
    {
        _particles.transform.position = gameObject.transform.position;
        _particles.Play();
    }
}
```

Comment: Извините что так долго не отвечал. Вроде все сделал как Вы и сказали, но до сих пор ничего не работает...Просто не появляется партикл.

Comment: @KraNf а сам партикл работает, если на сцену перетащить?

Comment: Да, сам партикл на сцене показывается, но при смерти врага нет.

Comment: Посмотри где находится партикл после смерти врага

Comment: На самой сцене он появляется на месте врага, но вот в самой игре партикла нету.

Comment: У тебя игра 2D? Посмотри на позицию по Z у партикла

Comment: Игра 2D, по Z все нормально. Проблема вообще какая то странная, у меня есть партикл который появляется когда происходит попадание по цели, и партикл который должен появляться после смерти, сделан по такому же методу, но он не работает. Отключать партикл попадания пытался, проблема точно не в нем.

Comment: Пока не могу придумать решение. Попробуй использовать эффект при попадании. Если он заработает, то дело в системе частиц(придется пересоздавать), а если нет, то единственное что могу придумать это позиция по Z, потому что у тебя на скрине враг на -500 позиции по z и вот так оно может не отображаться

Comment: Вы были полностью правы, все из за позиции врага по Z, поменял все на 0, и заработало.

Comment: Благодарю за помощь.